# Editing a proposal by you takes up too much place on the screen

Tags: feature-request, documentation

I made a proposal for an example on Documentation today. In a few minutes, I got a few comments telling me to make a few changes in my proposal. I agreed with all the changes, and went retracted and started editing.

Here is what it looked when I was editing:

[image]

The part used for editing the proposal took half the page. At the same time I was reading an example so that became very difficult. I found out that you can reduce the size of the portion so that it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPtk1.png), but still it disturbs me quite a lot when I'm reading something.

I couldn't find a way to minimize it, and clicking <kbd>Cancel</kbd> at the right bottom corner would return it back to the reviewers which I didn't want, as I had still not finished my edits.

Can we put a button to minimize this?

Comment: [Duplicate](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328461/huge-non-dismiss-able-red-bar-showed-up-after-i-started-editing-a-topic)?

Comment: @JNat I don't think so as that is talking about only the red part, while I'm asking about the whole thing.